# Question about strong induction

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots$ be the sequence of integers defined by $a_1=1$, $a_2=3$, $a_3=7$ and$$a_i=a_{i−1}+a_{i−2}+a_{i−3}$$ for each integer $i≥4$. Prove by strong induction that $a_n<2^n$ for all integers $n≥1$.

To be honest, I don't really understand the concept of strong induction like what is the difference between strong and normal induction. Based on the question above I have already done a base case:

- When $n = 1$, $a_i = 1$ and $1<2^1$ therefore true for $n = 1$.
- When $n = 2$, $a_i = 3$ and $3<2^2$ therefore true for $n = 2$.
- When $n = 3$, $a_i = 7$ and $7<2^3$ therefore true for $n = 3$.

However, I am not too sure about the induction step. I am a bit confused on how to implement this statement ($a_i = a_{i−1} + a_{i−2} + a_{i−3}$ for each integer $i ≥ 4$) into the induction. What approach should I take to prove the statement is true?

Answer (score 2):

The difference between regular induction and strong induction is that in regular induction you assume some predicate $P$ is true of $k$, then show from this that $P$ is true of $k+1$.  Along with a base case this proves the predicate is true for all naturals.  In strong induction you assume $P$ is true for all naturals less than or equal to $k$ and prove it for $k+1$.

In this problem your equation involves $a_{n-1}, a_{n-2},$ and $a_{n-3}$.  You want to use the fact that $a_k \lt 2^k$ for each of them.  This is what makes it strong induction as you use three instances of the induction hypothesis.  So assume $a_k \lt 2^k$ for all $k \lt n$ and say $$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}\\ \lt 2^{n-1}+2^{n-2}+2^{n-3}\\
=7\cdot 2^{n-3} \\\lt 8 \cdot 2^{n-3}\\=2^n$$
where we used the three instances going from the first line to the second.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $a_k<2^k$ for all $k<i$

$a_i=a_{i-1}+a_{i-2}+a_{i-3}\quad$ < $\quad2^{i-1}+2^{i-2}+2^{i-3}$

$RHS = 7*2^{i-3}$ < $8*2^{i-3}$ = $2^i$